# Setting Width for Sprite's Child Image

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sprite

I've a slider class (SliderUI) and I'm passing slider and track images to that class as sprites.

What I'm trying to do is, passing one more image as sprite and changing its width for doing masking in slider. (It will expand or collapse as you move volume slider)

When I try to change width of sprite, it doesn't show up and I guess sprite is just container and resizing it makes it disappeared.

So how can I resize sprite with its child image (it's loaded by a Loader object by the way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, resizing Sprite makes it dissapear. Manually setting up width and heights of the Sprite works like scaling, and when there's nothing drawn on the Sprite it won't be shown (since you can't set scale to "nothing").
If you want Sprite to have width and height, draw something on it, e.g. transparent rectangle:

```
sprite.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 0);
sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight);
```

Some more details here:
http://www.kirupa.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-274593.html

UPD:

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
sprite.addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("road_01.png"));
```

If you set size to sprite before image is loaded, the sprite won't show up.

Solution1: listen to Complete event in loader and set size after.

```
loader.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);

private function onImageLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    // whatever you want to make with sprite
    // e.g.
    sprite.width = 100;
}
```

Solution2: use sprite's `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties to resize it:

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
sprite.addChild(loader);
loader.load(new URLRequest("road_01.png"));
sprite.scaleX = 0.5;
```

Comment: I'm loading an image in sprite and I want to resize this image with sprite... How can I do that?

Comment: If I get it right, you've got something like this: `var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite;
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    sprite.addChild(loader);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("road_01.png"));` If you set size to sprite before image is loaded, the sprite won't show up. Solution1: listen to Complete event in loader `loader.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);` and set size after. Solution2: use sprite's `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties to resize it.